# Marshaling callback to native dll

Tags: c#

I am working with callback going from unmanged native library to my managed C# code.
Callback function is declared in header file:

```
typedef void* (TNotice)(wchar_t *msg, bool error);
```

Callback has string parameter msg.I don't khow, why doesn't work declaration in c#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate IntPtr CallbackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string msg, bool error);
```

but declaration:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate IntPtr CallbackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]StringBuilder msg, bool error);
```

works fine.

Comment: For me, the syntax looks correct. Except... In C# you say your function returns some pointer, while in C++ declaration returns `void`. It should not be the issue, but who know. Please specify what kind of behaviour you have - what means "doesn't work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a `StringBuilder`, because the parameter is an `out` parameter or return value. In those cases you cannot use a regular `string`. The marshalling you use is correct.

Comment: Should it still be string builder if used in a struct?